# The application did not respond Discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I just learned some basics of discord.js and I'm currently trying out the ping command. And im testing the command in discord but problem right now is that when i call interaction, i got respond message **The application did not respond** but i dont get any error in my code.

This is my main code

```
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');

const { Client, Collection, Events, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

client.commands = new Collection();

const foldersPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath);

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commandsPath = path.join(foldersPath, folder);
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
        const command = require(filePath);
        if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
            client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
        } else {
            console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
        }
    }
}

client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
    const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) {
        console.error(`No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`);
        return;
    }


    console.log(interaction);
});




client.once(Events.ClientReady, readyClient => {
    console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${readyClient.user.tag}`);
});




client.login(token);
```

and this is my ping.js

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ping')
        .setDescription('Replies with Pong!'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply('Pong!');
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you've added the execution of the Interaction event. It looks like you're using the [discord.js](https://discordjs.guide) guide, if not I would suggest using it. Here is what you should be able to replace your Interaction event with:

```js
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) {
        console.error(`No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`);
        return;
    }

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        if (interaction.replied || interaction.deferred) {
            await interaction.followUp({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
        } else {
            await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
        }
    }
});
```